# BlackBerry WebWorks 2.1.1, OS 6.0 / 7.0, blackberry.pim.Appointment.find is not working

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I have a simple sample app that returns number of appointments in calendar app, which works fine in OS 5.0, but failing find any appointments in OS 6.0 or 7.0, (I can create an Appointment though, just can't find it)

```
 var date = new Date();
 var filter = new blackberry.find.FilterExpression("start", ">=", date);
 var appts = blackberry.pim.Appointment.find(filter);
```

or just

```
 var appts = blackberry.pim.Appointment.find();
```

config file:

```
 <feature id="blackberry.system" />
 <feature id="blackberry.utils" />
 <feature id="blackberry.io.file" />
 <feature id="blackberry.find"/>
 <feature id="blackberry.pim.Appointment"/>
 <feature id="blackberry.pim.Attendee" />
 <feature id="blackberry.pim.Recurrence" />
 <feature id="blackberry.pim.Reminder" />
```

[I think this thread might be related to the problem I'm having, but it indicates that the problem has been fixed in WebWorks 2.0](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Date-FilterExpressions-not-working-with-Appointment-find-on-OS6/td-p/833737).

[Appointment API](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/webworks/api/blackberry.pim.Appointment.html).

Edit:

Simulators:

- 5.0.0.975 - 9630-Verizon - OK
- 6.0.0.141 - 9800 - ERR
- 7.0.0.318 - 9930 - ERR

Device:

- 6.0.0.600 - 9800 - ERR

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? We're having the same problem.

Comment: no, unfortunately I couldn't figure that out.